# problema con uso de punteros en C y paso por referencia

Tags: c

No entiendo por que no pone el asterisco en `int end = strlen(str) - 1;`, ¿No seria `int end = strlen(*str) - 1;` ?

```
void trim(char *str) // Remove whitespace from a string and properly null-
terminate it.
{
int i;
int begin = 0;
int end = strlen(str) - 1;
while (isspace(str[begin])) begin++;
while ((end >= begin) && isspace(str[end])) end--;
for (i = begin; i <= end; i++) str[i - begin] = str[i];
str[i - begin] = '\0';
}
```

Tengo entendido que poniendo punteros por paso de referencia necesitas un apuntador.

Answer (score 2):

En C no existe un tipo string como en otros lenguajes. No existe un tipo de datos para almacenar texto, se utilizan arrays de chars, que funcionan igual que los demás arrays. Vemos cosas curiosas como por ejemplo que en el scanf no se usa el símbolo &. No hace falta porque es un array, y ya sabemos que escribir el nombre del array es equivalente a poner &nombre[0].

Por lo tanto, si te fijas en la declaración de la función que estás examinando esta recibiendo un puntero a una dirección de memoria, precisamente a la primera posición de la cadena, es decir que "str" apunta al primera caracter, si lo imprimes como

```
printf("%p", str);
```

Verás su dirección, sim embargo si lo imprimes como

```
printf("%s", str);
```

Verás su contenido hasta que encuentre el caracter NULO o de fin de cadena '\0'

Un saludo.

EDITO: Si usarías el asterisco, obtendrías el primer carácter de la cadena, es decir, si pruebas

```
printf("%c", *str);
```

Verías el primer carácter

Answer (score 1):

Los punteros son uno de los grandes potenciales de C y C++ por provenir de C pues los heredo, pero es una característica de C. Tienes una confusión en la manera que trabajan los punteros, los punteros son un tipo de dato el cual solo se puede guardar una **dirección de memoria**, osea apuntan(punteros) a una dirección de memoria, una dirección de memoria que ya ha sido asignada a otra variable o de manera dinámica([Gestión de memoria](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory)), pero debe ser una dirección de memoria **que existe** y que ya fue **asignada**. Cuando defines un puntero siempre lleva el característico asterisco antes del nombre, y para utilizarlo se puede hacer de diferentes maneras, ademas con los punteros se puede utilizar algo llamado [aritmética de punteros](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_C/Punteros#Operaciones_Aritm%C3%A9ticas), con un ejemplo extremadamente básico puede que ayude a ponerte en contexto:

```
int numeroINT = 100;
double numeroD = 50.025;

const char *texto = "En C no existe el objeto de alto nivel llamado String";

int *ptrInt = &numeroINT;
double *ptrD = &numeroD;
```

Como puedes observar, declaro dos variables, una `int` y la otra tipo `double`, y un puntero constante a `char` el cual apunta a una cadena de texto, que no puede ser cambiada por ser un puntero constante.

Se declaran dos punteros, uno a tipo `int` y otro a tipo `double`, y a estos se les pasa la dirección de memoria de dos variables del mismo tipo, así que esos punteros quedan apuntando a la dirección de memoria de esas dos variables.

Ahora con estos dos punteros se pueden modificar las dos variables, porque los punteros tienen su dirección de memoria ya asignada, siguiendo con el ejemplo anterior:

```
void imprimir_texto(const char *texto)
{
    printf("%s\n", texto);
}

void aumentar_numero(int *numero)
{
    ++(*numero);
}

imprimir_texto(texto);
//Estas dos llamadas son equivalentes
aumentar_numero(ptrInt);
aumentar_numero(&numeroINT);
```

Dale un vistazo a esas dos funciones, una recibe un puntero constante a `char` y lo imprime, y el otro recibe un puntero o dirección de memoria a un tipo de dato `int`, y su valor lo aumenta en 1.

Cuando se utiliza un puntero, se hace de dos maneras, una es utilizarlo sin el asterisco, esto quiere decir que se esta llamando es a la dirección de memoria, pero si se le pone el asterisco, se esta llamando es al **valor** guardado en esa dirección, son dos vainas muy diferentes.

Que ventajas tiene utilizar punteros, es una pregunta que me hacia cuando los vi por primera vez, supón que tienes una estructura increíblemente grande y pesada y requiere que pase por muchísimas funciones, los valores pasados a funciones son pasados por valor, osea que se hace una copia del objeto original y se pasa la copia, y si tu estructura es muy grande, esa copia llevara su ratooo, bajando considerablemente el rendimiento, una solución sencilla a esto es pasar la dirección de memoria(puntero) de la estructura, con esto se pasa la original en vez de realizar una copia, agregándole esto puedes proteger la estructura original contra copia agregándole la palabra reservada `const` delante de la definición, de la misma manera que lo hice con el texto.

Answer (score 1):

> ¿No seria `int end = strlen(*str) - 1;`?

- `str` es un puntero a `char`
- `*str` es un `char`

La función `strlen` necesita recibir un **puntero a char** para poder recorrer la cadena hasta el final y saber así su longitud.

Así que no, no habría que usar el asterisco en este caso.

Answer (score 0):

El asterisco solo es usado a la hora de declarar o modificar un puntero.

Ejemplo:

```
char *cadena = "texto original"; //asigno
char **direccionDe = &cadena;
(*direccionDe) = "nuevo texto"; //modifico
printf("%s", cadena); //nuevo texto
```

En tu ejemplo solo estas obteniendo el tamaño de dicha cadena y restandole uno.